# grouping by count, year and displaying the last occurence and its count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following dataframe

```
d = {'year': [2001, 2002, 2005, 2002, 2004, 1999, 1890],
     'tin': [12, 23, 24, 28,30, 12,7],
     'ptin': [12, 23, 28, 22, 12, 12,0] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If I run following code:

```
df = (df.groupby(['ptin', 'tin', 'year'])
                  .apply(lambda x : x['tin'].isin(x['ptin']).astype(int).sum())
                  .reset_index(name='matches'))
df
```

I get following result

```
    ptin    tin   year   matches
0   12      3.0   1999   0
1   12      3.0   2001   0
2   22      1.0   2002   0
3   23      1.0   2002   0
```

This gives me the matching tin to ptin and groups by year.

Now if I want to find the last occurence of say for example tin == 12, I should get 2001. I want add that column as well as difference between 1999 and 2001, which is two in different column, such that my answer looks like below

```
    ptin    tin   year   matches    lastoccurence   length 
0   12      3.0   1999   0            0               0
1   12      3.0   2001   0            2001            2
2   22      1.0   2002   0            2002            1
3   23      1.0   2002   0            2002            1
```

Any help would be appreciated. I could take solution in either pandas or SQL if that is possible.

Comment: Please line up the formatting of your data, and correct mistakes such as `1999` showing up as `199`.  The more attention to detail shown in your own question the more likely people will invest their time to try to help you.

Comment: I guess you have ended up pasting the wrong values for tin and matches columns when you are trying to portray the result of your df.groupby chunk of code.

Comment: No. Those are sample values. There are tin and ptin values that may or not match. But my question is how to find those values and try to find the duration (length). Say if tin 12 occurred in 1999 and did not occur after 2001. Its length should be 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do magic (at least partially?):

```
df['duration'] = df.sort_values(['ptin','year']).groupby('ptin')['year'].diff()
df = df.dropna(subset=['duration'])
print (df)

     ptin  tin  year  matches  duration
2    12    12  2001        1       2.0
3    12    30  2004        0       3.0
```